# put content in block

Tags: html, css

I have some element and want to put all them in block when screen size is less than 900px

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<div class="dropdown">
  <img style="width:30px;height:auto;" src="/escapologinphpto.jpeg">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
          <!-- <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> -->
        </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is link of work till now
https://jsfiddle.net/153qkyoh/

Comment: Fine to know. What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/153qkyoh/

Comment: In your attempt you forgot `float: none` for `nav .collapse`. But I don't think it looks as expected, you show us just this.

Comment: What do you mean "_put all them in block_"? I don't understand what you are wanting to achieve. Like `display: block`?

Comment: He wants to achieve the vertical dropdown navigation.

Comment: even with the fiddle, its not clear...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the CSS media query. However, you need know the various breakpoints for certain devices and screen types.
We have 992px as a screen breakpoint which is the closest to 900px.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 992px) {
    a {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Or should incase the link elements display property is being inherited, you can add the - !important keyword to ignore all inherited styles connected to it.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 992px) {
    a {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```